# REST API custom resource objects and urls

Tags: api, rest, resources, salesforce

In thinking about how to design something like salesforce custom objects and expose them via REST.  So say a developer wants to create a bunch of custom objects like teachers, students, classes.  Now, each of these objects can potentially be made public, how would you deal with object/resource collisions in the Rest URL's?

For example:

/v1/objects/teachers is public

Then another developer decides they want to create a teachers object as well and make it public.  Well, teachers is obviously in a globally namespaced set of objects, no longer available.  It appears salesforce handles this by using a namespace for the objects, so it becomes something like:

/v1/objects/namespace/teachers

I'm curious about others thought on other ways to handle this?

I have thought about making them generate unique resource names no matter what...
Adding a namespace prefixed to the resource for every created resource...
?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the object "created date-time" instead of the namespace in the url.

/v1/objects/01112012002010/teachers

Unless someone creates the object at the same instance, this should work 99.99% of the time.

Anup